# iOS RemoteNotification swizzler infinity loop by two libraries

Tags: ios, firebase, react-native, apple-push-notifications, mixpanel

In my app, I'm using [Mixpanel iPhone](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone) library to record usage, and [Firebase iOS SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk) Messaging library to handle notifications.

The issue happens when the iOS app is in the background, after user tap on a notification toast, app launches but will crash in a few seconds. The failure appears to be an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` from Mixpanel's `mp_swizzledMethod_5` function.

While digging into the call stack I found that Mixpanel's [mp_swizzledMethod_5](https://github.com/mixpanel/mixpanel-iphone/blob/ff4961d5a2ee1537b7fa960ddc01b8788d0836f8/Mixpanel/MPSwizzler.m#L80) and Firebase's [FCM_swizzle_didReceiveNotificationResponseWithHandler](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/blob/6e6462e865e5202868f3478c73a72b082e05b205/Firebase/Messaging/FIRMessagingRemoteNotificationsProxy.m#L571) are calling each other infinitely. Please see this part of call stack

```
Thread 1 Queue : com.apple.main-thread (serial)
#0  0x0000000104f7a010 in is_interesting_event ()
#1  0x0000000104f7966c in gcd_queue_item_enqueue_hook ()
#2  0x00000001054bd1f0 in _dispatch_introspection_queue_item_enqueue_hook ()
#3  0x000000010548fa54 in dispatch_source_set_event_handler_f ()
#4  0x000000018256bce0 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol372$$libsqlite3.dylib ()
#5  0x00000001824cb7a0 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol18$$libsqlite3.dylib ()
#6  0x00000001824cb1d8 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol17$$libsqlite3.dylib ()
#7  0x0000000182527f80 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol159$$libsqlite3.dylib ()
#8  0x000000018252b878 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol167$$libsqlite3.dylib ()
#9  0x000000018252b220 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol164$$libsqlite3.dylib ()
#10 0x0000000182508048 in ___lldb_unnamed_symbol104$$libsqlite3.dylib ()
#11 0x00000001825037dc in sqlite3_step ()
#12 0x000000010480448c in -[FIRMessagingRmq2PersistentStore saveUnackedS2dMessageWithRmqId:] ()
#13 0x00000001048063e8 in -[FIRMessagingRmqManager saveS2dMessageWithRmqId:] ()
#14 0x00000001047ee768 in -[FIRMessaging appDidReceiveMessage:] ()
#15 0x0000000104802360 in FCM_swizzle_didReceiveNotificationResponseWithHandler ()
#16 0x000000010448388c in mp_swizzledMethod_5 at /Users/allanhahaha/Documents/craig_ios/CraigAtWork/workdl/ios/Mixpanel/MPSwizzler.m:85
#17 0x0000000104802380 in FCM_swizzle_didReceiveNotificationResponseWithHandler ()
#18 0x000000010448388c in mp_swizzledMethod_5 at /Users/allanhahaha/Documents/craig_ios/CraigAtWork/workdl/ios/Mixpanel/MPSwizzler.m:85
#19 0x0000000104802380 in FCM_swizzle_didReceiveNotificationResponseWithHandler ()

... thousands of lines of repeating calls

#6030   0x000000010448388c in mp_swizzledMethod_5 at /Users/allanhahaha/Documents/craig_ios/CraigAtWork/workdl/ios/Mixpanel/MPSwizzler.m:85
#6031   0x0000000104802380 in FCM_swizzle_didReceiveNotificationResponseWithHandler ()
#6032   0x000000010448388c in mp_swizzledMethod_5 at /Users/allanhahaha/Documents/craig_ios/CraigAtWork/workdl/ios/Mixpanel/MPSwizzler.m:85
#6033   0x0000000104802380 in FCM_swizzle_didReceiveNotificationResponseWithHandler ()
#6034   0x000000010448388c in mp_swizzledMethod_5 at /Users/allanhahaha/Documents/craig_ios/CraigAtWork/workdl/ios/Mixpanel/MPSwizzler.m:85
#6035   0x0000000104802380 in FCM_swizzle_didReceiveNotificationResponseWithHandler ()
#6036   0x000000018b8f6064 in -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] ()
#6037   0x000000018bb82af8 in -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] ()
#6038   0x000000018c3077c0 in __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke ()
#6039   0x000000018c307664 in -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] ()
#6040   0x000000018c0752cc in __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke ()
#6041   0x000000018c20e3cc in _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext ()
#6042   0x000000018c07517c in -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] ()
#6043   0x000000018be59760 in -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] ()
#6044   0x000000018bcfb2a8 in -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] ()
#6045   0x000000018478aca4 in __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.362 ()
#6046   0x000000010548d28c in _dispatch_client_callout ()
#6047   0x00000001054999e4 in _dispatch_block_invoke_direct ()
#6048   0x00000001847be7f8 in __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ ()
#6049   0x00000001847be49c in -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] ()
#6050   0x00000001847bea38 in -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] ()
#6051   0x000000018206f77c in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#6052   0x000000018206f6fc in __CFRunLoopDoSource0 ()
#6053   0x000000018206ef84 in __CFRunLoopDoSources0 ()
#6054   0x000000018206cb5c in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#6055   0x0000000181f8cc58 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#6056   0x0000000183e38f84 in GSEventRunModal ()
#6057   0x000000018b6e55c4 in UIApplicationMain ()
#6058   0x00000001044b5b48 in main at /Users/allanhahaha/Documents/craig_ios/CraigAtWork/workdl/ios/workdl/main.m:14
#6059   0x0000000181aac56c in start ()
```

Please help me understand what might take to fix it... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Figured out. Both of Firebase and Mixpanel are swizzling notification handlers, so I disabled notification swizzler in Mixpanel by adding

```
#define MIXPANEL_NO_NOTIFICATION_AB_TEST_SUPPORT 1
```

on top of `Mixpanel.h` before `@implementation Mixpanel`

Comment: Thanks this has been taking up all my time and your solution seems to work for me too. Is there a way to configure this from cocoa pods so it is not overwritten on each install?